# How to Change Array Format in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, format, resultset

I want to change my array format from

```
Array
(
    [profileImg] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => index.jpg
                    [1] => index1.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => D:\xampp\tmp\php714F.tmp
                    [1] => D:\xampp\tmp\php714F.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 13543
                    [1] => 23543
                )

        )

)
```

To

```
array(
    [name] => index.jpg,
    [type] => image/jpeg,
    [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php714F.tmp,
    [error] => 0,
    [size] => 13543
)

array(
    [name] => index1.jpg,
    [type] => image/jpeg,
    [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php714F.tmp,
    [error] => 0,
    [size] => 23543
)
```

I am getting this from my form

```
<input name="profileImg[]" type="file" />
```

Any Help would be appreciate, Thanks

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: i tried with foreach but can't find the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
$result = [];
foreach($_FILES['profileImg'] as $k => $d){
 foreach($d as $key => $val){
   $result[$key][$k] = $d[$key];
  }
}
```

`print_r($result);` returns,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => index.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php714F.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 13543
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => index1.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\php714F.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 23543
        )

)
```

Comment: your code have some mistakes, but after some correction its working just fine thanks Ben.

Comment: This is correct syntax, as of PHP 5.4. `As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].` If you're using an older version, then just replace it with `array()`.

Comment: I am using the latest version and i know what to do. Just inform you too and the other visitors. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4):

This would be what you want.

```
<?php

$result = array();
foreach ($list['profileImg'] as $key => $keyList)
{
    foreach ($keyList as $index => $value)
    {
        $result[$index][$key] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Works fine without a green tick. :(.

Comment: Hey Srain that would be partiality between you and Ben because nobody voted for him and he had answered just little bit before you.

Comment: aha! ^_^ , so kind of you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($_FILES['profileImg'] as $name => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
        $result[$key][$name] = $item;
    }
}
```

should do the trick.